# Determining the kernel of the localization map when defining the localization by generators and relations à la Serre

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

All rings considered will be commutative and unitary. Let $A$ be a ring, $S \subseteq A$ a multiplicatively closed subset. The localization $\lambda_S : A \longrightarrow A[S^{-1}]$ can be characterized as a ring homomorphism $\lambda : A \longrightarrow B$ with the following three properties:

- (LC1) $\lambda$ localizes $S$, i.e. $\lambda(s)$ is invertible in $B$ for all $s \in S$;
- (LC2) for every $b \in B$ there is $s \in S$ such that $s b \in \text{im $\lambda$}$;
- (LC3) $\ker \lambda = \{a \in A \,| \,\exists s \in S: sa = 0\}$.

One way to achieve this is to define the localization by means of generators and relations: take an indeterminate $T_s$ for each $s \in S$, form the polynomial ring $A[T] = A[T_s|s \in S]$ over $A$ in these indeterminates and quotient out the ideal generated by the $sT_s - 1$ , $s \in S$, thus defining the localization $A[S^{-1}]$:
\begin{equation*}
            A[S^{-1}] := A[T_s|s \in S]\,/\,(sT_s-1|s \in S).
    \end{equation*}
The structure map $\lambda_S : A \longrightarrow A[S^{-1}]$ then comes along as the composite
\begin{equation*}
            A \longrightarrow A[T_s|s \in S] \longrightarrow            A[S^{-1}].
    \end{equation*}
See [1], pp. I-7-8. The question is how to verify properties (LC1-3) for this construction. In fact, (LC1-2) are straightforward, but (LC3) seems hard. It is known to be true, since it holds in the other widespread model of localization, given by $\mu_S : A \longrightarrow S^{-1}A$ with
\begin{equation*}
            S^{-1}A := A \times S / \sim,
    \end{equation*}
where $\sim$ denotes the equivalence relation
\begin{equation*}
            (a,s) \sim (b,t) :\iff \exists u \in S:\, u(ta-sb) = 0,
    \end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
            \mu_S(a) := a/1,
    \end{equation*}
where, for $(a,s) \in A \times S$, $a/s$ denotes  its equivalence class in $S^{-1}A$. Here, $(LC3)$ is trivial for $\mu_S$, holding by construction. Since both $\lambda_S$ and $\mu_S$ are universal among the ring homomorphisms localizing $S$, it holds for $\lambda_S$, too. But to show this directly for $\lambda_S$ using its definition, is surprisingly difficult: if $\lambda_S(a) = 0$, this means there are $s_1, \dots s_n \in S$ and polynomials $p_1(T), \dots, p_n(T) \in A[T]$ such that ($T_i:=T_{s_i}$)
\begin{equation*}
            a = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i(T)(s_iT_i - 1).
    \end{equation*}
From this I can conclude
\begin{equation*}
            a = -\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \quad,\quad a_i := p_i(0)
    \end{equation*}
but this is, for the time being, the end of the flagpole. In the best
of all possible worlds, I would have $p_i(T) = a_i$; this would give
$a_is_i = 0$ for $i=1, \dots, n$, and so $sa = 0$ with $s := s_1 \cdots s_n$, but I see no reason for that.

So does somebody know what is needed to make progress towards (LC3)?

[1] Serre, J.-P.,
*Algèbre locale - Multiplicités*
(Lecture Notes in Mathematics 11). Springer 1965

Answer (score 6):

Here is a proof that $$\ker \lambda = \{ a \in A \, \vert \, sa = 0 \text{ for some } s \in S\} \quad (LC_3)$$ holds true assuming that the following definition is in use: $$A[S^{-1}] = A[T_s \vert s \in S] /\left(sT_s -1 \vert s \in S\right).$$

If $ta = 0$ for some $a \in A$ and some $t \in S$, then we have $$a = -(tT_t - 1)a \in (sT_s -1 \vert s \in S).$$ Hence the inclusion $\{ a \in A \, \vert \, sa = 0 \text{ for some } s \in S\} \subseteq \ker \lambda$ comes (almost) for free.

To prove the reverse inclusion, consider $a = \sum_{i = 1}^n p_i(T_1, \dots, T_n)(s_i T_i - 1) \in A[T_1, \dots, T_n]$ and reason by induction on $n \ge 1$.

Let us suppose that $n = 1$, i.e., $a = p_1(T_1)(s_1 T_1 - 1)$. Replacing simultaneously $a$ by $s_1^m a$ and $p_1(T_1)$ by $s_1^m p_1(T_1)$ for some $m > 0$ if need be, we can assume that either $p_1(T_1) = 0 = a$, or $\deg(s_1 p_1(T_1)) = \deg(p_1(T_1))$. As the latter identity is clearly impossible, the induction base is settled.

Suppose now that $n > 1$ and let $\overline{a}$ be the image of $a$ in $\overline{A}[T_1, \dots, T_{n - 1}] \simeq A[T_1, \dots, T_n]/(s_nT_n - 1)$ where $\overline{A} = A[T_n]/\left(s_n T_n - 1\right)$ (see claim below).
Since $\overline{a} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} \overline{p_i}(T_1, \dots, T_{n - 1}) (s_i T_i -1)$ where $\overline{p_i} \in\overline{A}[T_1, \dots, T_{n - 1}]$ is obtained from $p_i$ by assigning the last indeterminate $T_n$ to its image in $\overline{A}$, the induction hypothesis yields $s \overline{a} = 0$ for some $s \in S$. This means that $sa \in (s_n T_n - 1) \subset A[T_n]$ so that we can conclude by resorting to the case $n = 1$.$\square$

Note that we have used the following:

> **Claim.** Let $R$ be a commutative and unital ring. Let $R[T_1, \dots, T_n]$ be the ring of multivariate polynomials over $R$ with $n$ indeterminates $T_1, \dots, T_n$.  Let $P_1, \dots, P_k \in R[T_n]$ with $k \ge 0$. Then the natural isomorphism $R[T_1, \dots, ,T_n] \rightarrow (R[T_n])[T_1, \dots, T_{n - 1}]$ induces a ring isomorphism $R[T_1, \dots, T_n]/(P_1, \dots, P_k) \rightarrow \overline{R}[T_1, \dots, T_{n - 1}]$ where $\overline{R} \Doteq R[T_n]/(P_1, \dots, P_k)$.

Comment: When you say $\deg(s_1 p_1(T_1)) = \deg(p_1(T_1))$, did you perhaps mean to say on the left hand side $\deg(s_1 T_1 p_1(T_1))$?

Comment: @ZachTeitler Dear Zach, thanks for your interest and careful reading. I actually meant what I wrote initially. I have now expanded the aforementioned sentence to make the idea clearer: we multiply both hands by $s_1$ until either $p_1(T_1)$ gets annihilated (we are then done) or its degree does not decrease after a further multiplication by $s_1$. This would mean that $\deg(s_1p_1(T_1)) = \deg(p_1(T_1))$ and hence  $\deg(s_1T_1p_1(T_1)) = \deg(p_1(T_1)) + 1$. The latter is impossible as $\deg(a) = 0$. If it still looks odd, awkward or wrong, I'll be glad to follow your suggestion.

Comment: It makes sense! Thank you.

Comment: Dear Luc Guyot, many thanks for your suggestions of a proof. I have not
been able to fully retrace your chain of argument as it seems to me that
some points remain unsaid. But the indication that an inductive proof 
might be within reach was helpful, and I  will give an ouline of
proof as I have conveived it below as a separate answer.

Comment: Dear @MathCrawler, I didn't design my answer as a suggestion. Is it too concise?. I understand that several points remain unclear to you. Without a detailed feedback, it is difficult to improve. (I just made some edits though.)

Answer (score 2):

The proof of (LC3), in the given setting, is surprisingly difficult, or, at least, elaborate. Let $a \in A$ with $\lambda_S(a) = [a] = 0$ in $A[S^{-1}]$,
i.e. one has
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
    a \in (sT_s-1\,|\,s \in S).
\end{equation}
To show is that
\begin{equation}
\tag{2}
    sa = 0
\end{equation}
for some $s \in S$. Because of (1), there are elements $s_1, \dots s_n \in S$ and polynomials $p_1(T), \dots,p_m(T) \in A[T]$  such that
\begin{equation}
    a = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i(T) (s_iT_i - 1) \quad
    \text{in $A[T]$},\quad,\quad T_i := T_{s_i}.
    \end{equation}
As a first reduction, we may assume $p_i(T) = p_i(T_1, \dots,T_n)$ for all $i$, so that
\begin{equation}
\tag{3}
    a = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i(T_1, \dots, T_n) (s_iT_i - 1)  
    \quad \text{in $A[T]$}.
\end{equation}
Namely, let $T' \subseteq T$ be those indeterminates which either equal some $T_i$, or which appear in at least one $p_i(T)$, $i = 1, \dots, n$, so that we may write $T' = \{T_1, \dots, T_n, T_{n+1}, \dots, T_q\}$.
By eventually introducing dummy terms with coefficient 0, we may assume $p_i(T) = p_i(T') = p_i(T_1, \dots, T_q)$, so that $$a = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i(T_1, \dots, T_q) (s_iT_i - 1)$$. Putting $p_i(T):=0$ for $i=n+1, \dots, q$ then gives
\begin{equation*}
    a = \sum_{i=1}^q p_i(T_1, \dots, T_q) (s_iT_i - 1) 
    \quad \text{in $A[T]$},
\end{equation*}
which upon renaming $q$ by $n$ gives (3).

To prove that $sa = 0$ for some $s \in S$ we proceed by induction on $n$. For $n = 1$ we start with
\begin{equation*}
    a = p(T_s) (sT_s - 1) \quad \text{in $A[T]$}
\end{equation*}
for some indeterminate $T_s \in X$. We abbreviate notation by writing $u := T_s$, so that we have the equation
\begin{equation}
    a = p(u) (su - 1) \quad \text{in $A[T]$}.
\end{equation}
Let $p(u) = \sum_{k=0}^d a_k u^k$; then
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    p(u) (su - 1) 
    &= \sum_{k=0}^d sa_k u^{k+1}-\sum_{k=0}^d a_ku^k\\
    &= \sum_{k=1}^{d+1} sa_{k-1} u^k - 
        \sum_{k=0}^d a_k u^k\\
    &= sa_du^d + \sum_{k=1}^d(sa_{k-1}-a_k) u^k-a_0\\
    &= a,
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
so that
\begin{equation*}
    a_0=-a \quad,\quad a_k=sa_{k-1}\,,\,k=1,\dots, d-1 
    \quad,\quad sa_d = 0,
\end{equation*}
hence
\begin{equation*}
    a_k = -s^ka \,,\, k=0, \dots, d \quad,\quad 
    sa_d = 0 ,
\end{equation*}
so that
\begin{equation*}
        s^{d+1}a = -sa_d = 0,
\end{equation*}
as was to be shown. This establishes the base clause of the induction.

We now assume that $n \ge 1$, and that, with $k < n$,
\begin{equation*}
    a = \sum_{i=1}^k p_i(T_1,\dots,T_n)(s_iT_i-1) 
    \quad \text{in $A[T]$}
\end{equation*}
implies that $sa = 0$ for some $s \in S$, and we want to show that the same is true for $k = n$. So we assume, with a given ring $A$, that $a \in \ker \lambda_S$ and (2) holds. We put $A' := A[T_n]/(s_nT_n - 1)$. The projection $A \longrightarrow A'$ then realizes(!) the  localization $$\lambda_{S'} : A \longrightarrow A[S'^{-1}]$$ with $S' := \{s_n\}$; in particular, $A'= A[S'^{-1}]$. The canonical map
\begin{equation*}
    A[T_n] \longrightarrow A[T] \longrightarrow 
    A[S^{-1}]
\end{equation*}
induces, by passing to the quotient, $$A'= A[S'^{-1}] \longrightarrow A[S^{-1}] = (A[S'^{-1}])[S^{-1}]$$, which realizes the localization
\begin{equation*}
    \lambda_S' : A[S'^{-1}] \longrightarrow (A[S'^{-1}])  
    [S^{-1}].
\end{equation*}
The localization map $\lambda_S : A \longrightarrow A[S^{-1}]$ then factors as the composite of localizations
\begin{equation*}
    A \longrightarrow A' \longrightarrow A[S^{-1}] = 
    A \longrightarrow A[S'^{-1}] \longrightarrow 
    (A[S'^{-1}])[S^{-1}].
\end{equation*}
Let $\overline{a} \in A' = A[S'^{-1}]$ be the image of $a \in A$ under $A \longrightarrow A'$. Then $\lambda_S(a) = \lambda_S'(\overline{a}) = 0$. and so, by (3),
\begin{equation*}
    \overline{a} = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 
    \overline{p_i}(T_1, \dots, T_{n-1}) (s_iT_i - 1) 
    \quad \text{in $A'[T]$}
\end{equation*}
with $\overline{p_i}(T_1, \dots, T_{n-1}) = p_i(T_1,\dots, T_{n-1},1/s_n)$, $i=1, \dots, n-1$, since $s_nT_n - 1 = 0$ in $A' = A[S'^{-1}]$. Therefore, by the induction  hypothesis, $s\overline{a} = \overline{sa} = 0$ for some $s \in S$. Thus $sa \in \ker \lambda_{S'}$, and so, by the base clause $n=1$ applied to $\lambda_{S'}$,
\begin{equation*}
    s_n^{d+1}(sa) = (s_n^{d+1}s)a = 0,
\end{equation*}
which finishes the proof. As a byproduct of the proof we obtain that $s$ in (2)
may be chosen as a product of the $s_i$'s (with repeated factors), i.e. as
an element of the multiplicative closure of $\{s_1, \dots, s_n\}$.